How to map memtest bad memory location to memory DIMM number
One of my rack servers (running Ubuntu 22.04) is having random segfault error over the last few weeks. I suspect that it is caused by bad memory despite it has only been online for 4 months. The server has a Asrock TRX40 mobo, Threadripper 3990x CPU and 256GB memory.
I am wondering if there is a general approach to identify which DIMM of the memory should be replaced from the failing address printed by memtest (pcmemtest, memtest86+ etc)?
for example, below is a test I ran recently from the problematic server. The server has 8x DIMMs of DDR4 memory, each has 32GB size, with a total of 256GB.
the failing address is 00006a8e7c58. can I tell which DIMM should be replaced?
I found online there are some old articles on parsing different bits of the address for DDR2, although I still can't see where I can find the DIMM number.
thanks


00006a8e7c58 is 1787722840 (1,664946638048 GiB), which is also on the screen... Assuming those are physical addresses and that the memory space would be mapped contiguously with respect to the DIMMS' order (I'm not too familiar with this low-level stuff), I'd wager the first DIMM (slot #0 as reported on the motherboard)? I don't expect you to just try and remove it and run another test for 30 hours, so pretty much an unuseful comment, but I guess that unless you rephrase the question asking for a way to tackle this using Ubuntu specifically it will be closed as off-topic.

is the global address linear across the DIMMs? I have A1/A2/B1/B2/C1/C2/D1/D2 8 slots. is there a way to know how the A1-D2 slots are ordered along the incremental address direction?

That's exactly what I don't know, or I would have told you... I'd guess they would be, but I really can't tell for sure

There's also the multi-channel thing that might come into play, perhaps it makes more sense to map memory according to the channell... So A1, B1, C1 and so on... I could only make a bunch of speculations ultimately. Sorry, again, I suggest you rephrase the question asking for a way to tackle this using Ubuntu specifically. At the very least you should run the test using the memtest version that comes with the Ubuntu ISO to make it on-topic here, otherwise you're asking on a site about Ubuntu how to diagnose a hardware malfunction on a server using software that has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

the server is running Ubuntu 22.04. I did not use memtest86+ - it does not show up in my grub menu. Instead, I installed pcmemtest via apt-get and run it at boot time.

Well I have to apologize, I didn't know it was on Ubuntu repositories. I guess it would be on-topic then, I don't know, the community is usually split about hardware questions.  My personal stance is as long as someone is using softiware available on Ubuntu to diagnose the issue, then it's fine. Hopefully someone will chime in and give some more insights as to how to tackle this.
